# What is the correct path string I need for saving files to Azure Apps virtual applications and directories?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm using ASP.NET5 / MVC 6. I am trying to use a SQL logger on an app running in Azure Apps. Locally, I can access the directory I want, so I am pretty sure its not a syntax or system agnostic error. This is the part that fails while stepping through on remote debugging. Again, locally it runs and logs normally.

```
//Local path
private static readonly string _logFilePath = @"C\temp\DatabaseLog.sql";

//Azure App path
private static readonly string _logFilePath = @"\templog\DatabaseLog.sql";

public void Log(LogLevel logLevel, int eventId, object state, Exception exception, Func<object, Exception, string> formatter)
{
    var message = string.Format(
    "\n\n--{0}\n{1}",
    DateTime.Now,
    formatter(state, exception));//.Replace(", [", ",\n  ["));

    File.AppendAllText(_logFilePath, message); // <-- FAILS HERE
}
```

I have set \templog as a virtual directory in the Azure portal. See image:[image]

I have also created the folder in the project. See image:

[image]

Comment: I currently have Application unchecked for the /templog directory. At the time of the OP, it was checked. Neither way makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

The Azure App storage is mapped to d:\home so I would try to change:

```
    //Azure App path
    private static readonly string _logFilePath = @"\templog\DatabaseLog.sql";
```

to

```
    //Azure App path
    private static readonly string _logFilePath = @"d:\site\templog\DatabaseLog.sql";
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you still have to map the virtual path to physical?

using either of

```
private static readonly string _logFilePath = Server.MapPath(@"/templog/DatabaseLog.sql");
```

or

```
private static readonly string _logFilePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"/templog/DatabaseLog.sql");
```

Have you tried writing to /App_Data?
Does the folder exist on azure?
Maybe there are permissions on the folder that need to be set?

Comment: There is no App_data directory in MVC6. The Azure gui is pretty limited in allowing permissions.